# Volumetrics in EEVEE working in viewport but not in final render

Tags: volumetrics, eevee-render-engine

Hey so I'm working on a scene with volumetrics enabled in the Eevee render setting (volumetric lightning is on as well).

It shows up in the viewport and it looks fantastic, but as soon as I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render it out, everything is ok except the volumetrics are not present.

Any idea if it's a bug or I'm doing something wrong somewhere?

Running Blender 2.8 on OSX Mojave (10.14).

Comment: Make sure the maximum distance for volumetrics to render is sufficient in the volumetric tab, in Eevee's render settings.

Comment: I have the same issue (Blender 2.8rc1) and everything is set correctly AFAICT. Looks great in viewport, renders without volume effects (and same problem in Cycles).

Comment: few things to check:  1. are you using transparent background?  2.add sun to scene  3. lower volumetric samples

Comment: Me too blender 2.83.1 working in viewport

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. On your viewport, disable all your overlays and switch to *Render View*. Click *View*, then *Viewport Render Animation*. You can increase your render preview sample equal to the final render too. I did that before when Blender crashed when using conventional render.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved it yet, but I realised that if you have cycles rendering insted of eeve it seem to look different the render to the viewport, so the volumetric lights are not seen.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue here. The problem I was having is that I was rendering via viewport, instead of actually rendering. The difference is that when rendering from viewport, the function is designed to be somewhat speedier than an actual render. So if your volumetric samples are set higher than your render samples, it will default to the lower value. long story short, never ever render from viewport, unless you are simply testing animations/materials.